# Prevent Thunderbird in plaintext viewing mode from displaying images

Tags: images, thunderbird

I received a mail that was marked as spam in the title by the university server, but not in Thunderbird. I was surprised to find that Thunderbird actually displayed images in the message body, which were also attached.

I have set the viewing mode to plaintext, and set everything off that I could find under settings. I even opened the config editor and searched for inline and attachment, but to no avail, the settings were already as I expected.

Is there a method to prevent Thunderbird from displaying images automatically? Like an even plainer than plaintext mode?

Note: I already asked this question on https://stackoverflow.com/q/44164442 , but I was told it was off-topic and I should try here.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

In  Thunderbird, go to Tools -> Options -> 
Select 'Privacy' Tab

Deselect 'Allow Remote Content in Messages'

If this doesn't work - as for OP, try;
Go to Tools -> Options -> Select 'Advanced' Tab
Go to General Tab
Open Config Editor. Change switch of  mailnews.message_display.disable_remote_image to FALSE

Comment: Is already deselected

Comment: Try Tools -> Options -> Select 'Advanced' Tab
Go to General Tab
Open Config Editor. Change switch of  mailnews.message_display.disable_remote_image to FALSE

Comment: Sorry for inept posting - I'm new here. ;/

Comment: No problem, but it doesn't helpt either.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in latest TB versions and might or might not only occur on malformed multipart/alternative messages: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1370841

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the images were attached.  In my experience, Thunderbird will preview image attachments below the main message body.  I don't know if there are any settings regarding automatic previewing of attachments, but they would certainly be separate from the "load external content" settings.

If an image is *attached* to an e-mail, it's embedded in the message just as much as the text is.  (In fact, attachments are often sent as base-64 encoded text, you can right-click and select "View message source" to see for yourself).

Privacy settings regulating external content won't affect attachments whatsoever - because the image is not an externally-hosted image, it's part of the *message itself*.

The privacy implications of loading external content are because a tracking pixel will have a URL like "example.org/track.png?userID=1234", and the example.org server will log whenever your user ID requests that image, implying that you opened the email.  However, if the image is attached to the message itself, there's no external servers involved in viewing that image.  You can test this yourself by disconnecting your Internet and opening various emails with attached images vs external images.